# Parsing plain text Markdown from a ContentEditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown, contenteditable

I know there are other questions on editable divs, but I couldn't find one specific to the Markdown-related issue I have.

User will be typing inside a ContentEditable div. And he may choose to do any number of Markdown-related things like code blocks, headers, and whatever.

I am having issues extracting the source properly and storing it into my database to be displayed again later by a standard Markdown parser. I have tried two ways:

1. `$('.content').text()`

In this method, the problem is that all the line breaks are stripped out and of course that is not okay.

2. `$('.content').html()`

In this method, I can get the line breaks working fine by using regex to replace `<br\>` with `\n` before inserting into database. But the browser also wraps things like `## Heading Here` with divs, like this: `<div>## Heading Here</div>`. This is problematic for me because when I go to display this afterwards, I don't get the proper Markdown formatting.

What's the best (most simple and reliable) way to solve this problem as of 2015?

**EDIT:** Found a potential solution here: http://www.davidtong.me/innerhtml-innertext-textcontent-html-and-text/

Answer (score 1):

if you check the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/) of jquery's `.text()` method,

> The result of the .text() method is a string containing the combined text of all matched elements. (Due to variations in the HTML parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines and other white space.)

so getting whitespaces is not guaranteed in all browsers.

try using the `innerText` property of the element.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].innerText
```

this returns the text with all white spacing intact.  But this is not cross browser compatible.  It works in IE and Chrome, but not in Firefox.

the innerText equivalent for Firefox is `textContent` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)), but that strips out the whitespaces.

Comment: @Anbarsasan is there anything that I can do for Firefox that doesn't strip whitespace?

Comment: i am not aware of any way for Firefox.  I initially tried the link that you posted before answering here, but the problem persisted for me in Firefox (31.8).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've been able to come up with using that link I posted above in my edit. It's in Coffeescript.

```
div = $('.content')[0]
if div.innerText
  text = div.innerText
else
  escapedText = div.innerHTML
              .replace(/(?:\r\<br\>|\r|\<br\>)/g, '\n')
              .replace(/(\<([^\>]+)\>)/gi, "")
  text = _.unescape(escapedText)
```

Basically, I'm checking whether or not innerText works, and if it doesn't then we do this other thing where we:

1. Take the HTML, which has escaped text.
2. Replace all the `<br>` tags with line breaks.
3. Strip out any tags (escaped ones won't be stripped, i.e. the stuff the user types).
4. Unescape the escaped text.